# How to correctly recover when WatchKey.reset() returns false?

Tags: java-8, nio

I have a long running process that 'watches' a directory for file changes.

The new Java 8 'watcher' API makes it very clear that `WatchKey.reset()` must be called on references returned by `WatchService.take()`.  Note: The return result from `WatchKey.reset()` matches `WatchKey.isValid()`.

Yesterday, my long running process observed many file updates and `WatchKey.reset()` normally returned `true`.  However, for reasons I do not understand, a one call to `WatchKey.reset()` returned `false`.

1. What is the meaning of return value `false` from `WatchKey.reset()`?  The official tutorial says: "If the key is no longer valid, the directory is inaccessible so exit the loop."
2. How do I recover from this state?  I wish to continue monitoring the directory for file changes.  The [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) and [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#reset--) does not explain how to do this.

For those less familiar with this new API, here is some setup code:

```
public static void main(String[] argArr)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    final File dirPath = new File(argArr[0]);
    if (! dirPath.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(argArr[0]);
    }
    final Path dirPath2 = dirPath.toPath();
    try (final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {

        final WatchKey registerWatchKey =
            dirPath2.register(
                watchService,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);

        try {
            while (true) {
                // blocking
                final WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
                final List<WatchEvent<?>> watchEventList = watchKey.pollEvents();
                for (final WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : watchEventList) {
                    // use 'watchEvent'
                }
                final boolean isValid = watchKey.reset();
                if (! isValid) {
                    // How to recover here?  I want to continue monitoring dirPath2.
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            registerWatchKey.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `register` again? I suppose, that’ll give you an `IOException`, if the directory does not exist or is inaccessible. Otherwise, the directory might have been temporarily inaccessible or the `WatchEvent` might have been truly cancelled.

Comment: @Holger: Good point.  Digging deeper, I also noticed that when `watchKey.reset()` returns `false`, then `registerWatchKey.isValid()` *also* returns `false`.  I will try re-register.  Stil... *why* is this happening?  So mysterious.  Nothing in the docs.  As soon as watchKey is invalid, I check if dir exists -- and it does.